# How can I easily reference separate js / css files for debugging when using gulp or grunt?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gulp, gruntjs, bundling-and-minification

I'm developing a legacy ASP.NET MVC 5 project which still uses ASP.NET Bundling and Minification. I'm interested in switching to Gulp or Grunt, because I need to save source maps for my js files.

It seems easy to generate a minified script bundle with Gulp or Grunt, but what I do not understand yet is the recommended setup for loading single js files when debugging and minified bundles in production. I guess it would be quite easy to generate a razor view for including the scripts as part of my Grunt / Gulp compilation process, but it feels like re-inventing the wheel.

For instance, in ASP.NET MVC i can write something like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyJSBundle")
```

and it will automatically load separate js files in development and a single script bundle in production. What is the easiest way achieve this with Gulp or Grunt?

Comment: Perhaps clarify what you mean by; _"setup for loading single js files when debugging and minified bundles in production"_. Typically when using grunt you generate 2 x builds (one "dev" and one "dist"), Grunt plugins (such as [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml)) provide a way to update any links to `.js` assets in the `.html` file. For example, let's say your source `.html` contains two links; `<script src="dir/file-a.js"/>` and `<script src="dir/file-b.js"/>`. They can be substituted with e.g. `<script src="dir/bundle.min.js"/>` during the "dist" build step.

Comment: @RobC: This solves exactly same problem that I described, though with a slightly different approach. Thanks very much! If you could write the same information in an answer, I will gladly award the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer:

Typically when using Grunt you generate two builds - one for *"dev" (development)* and another for *"dist" (distribution/production)*. Whereby for the scenario you've described;

- Both the *"dev"* and *"dist"* builds generate a single concatenated/minified file version (e.g. `bundle.min.js`) derived from multiple source `.js` files.
- However, only the *"dev"* build generates an additional Source Map file(s),  that holds information about your original `.js` files, for the purpose of debugging during the development lifecycle.

Grunt plugins, such as [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml), provide a way to update any links to `.js` assets in the `.html` file. For example, let's say your source `.html` contains these two links;

```html
<script src="js/a.js"/>
<script src="js/b.js"/>
```

They can be substituted during the *"dist"* and/or *"dev"* build step to the following single `<script>` element:

```html
<script src="dir/bundle.min.js"/>
```

---

#### Example demo:

The following somewhat contrived example demonstrates how you may approach your requirement using Grunt.

1. Let's say our initial project directory is structured as follows:

   ```
   project
   ├── Gruntfile.js
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   ├── package.json
   └── src
       ├── index.html
       └── js
           ├── a.js
           └── b.js
   ```

   Note, in the `src` directory we have a single `index.html` file, and two `.js` files in the `js` directory.
2. In the contents of `index.html` shown below it contains two `<script>` elements, each one referencing a `.js` file.

   **project/src/index.html**

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>

   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>demo</title>
   </head>

   <body>

     <!--build:js js/bundle.min.js-->
     <script src="js/a.js"></script>
     <script src="js/b.js"></script>
     <!--/build-->
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

   Note, the custom HTML comments encasing both `<script>` elements. These [custom HTML comments](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml#simple-examples) are utilized by `grunt-processhtml`. The part that reads; `js/bundle.min.js` in the comment essentially defines the new pathname to be used.
3. Let's consider the following `Gruntfile.js` configuration:

   **Gruntfile.js**

   ```js
   module.exports = function (grunt) {

     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');

     grunt.initConfig({

       // 1. Concatenate .js files.
       concat: {
         dist: {
           src: [
             'src/js/a.js',
             'src/js/b.js'
           ],
           dest: './dist/js/bundle.min.js'
         },
         dev: {
           options: {
             sourceMap: true
           },
           src: [
             'src/js/a.js',
             'src/js/b.js'
           ],
           dest: './dev/js/bundle.min.js'
         }
       },

       // 2. Minify .js files.
       uglify: {
         dist: {
           files: {
             './dist/js/bundle.min.js': './dist/js/bundle.min.js' // dest : src
           }
         },
         dev: {
           options: {
             mangle: false,
             sourceMap: true,
             sourceMapIn: './dev/js/bundle.min.js.map'
           },
           files: {
             './dev/js/bundle.min.js': './dev/js/bundle.min.js' // dest : src
           }
         }
       },

       // 2. Process .html file.
       processhtml: {
         dist: {
           files: {
             './dist/index.html': './src/index.html' // dest : src
           }
         },
         dev: {
           files: {
             './dev/index.html': './src/index.html' // dest : src
           }
         }
       }

     });


     grunt.registerTask('default', ['dist', 'dev']);

     grunt.registerTask('dist', [
       'concat:dist',
       'uglify:dist',
       'processhtml:dist'
     ]);

     grunt.registerTask('dev', [
       'concat:dev',
       'uglify:dev',
       'processhtml:dev'
     ]);

   };
   ```

   **Explanation of Gruntfile.js:**

   - In addition to the previously mentioned `grunt-processhtml` plugin the following two are also utilized in this example:

     - [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) - for concatenating the two `.js` files.
     - [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) - for minifying the `.js` file.

       <sub>**Note:** There are other plugins available for these types of task. I have chosen these additional two plugins for the purpose of this demonstration.</sub>
   - Each of the three *Tasks* (`concat`, `uglify`, and `processhtml`) contain two separate *[Targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets)* named `dist` and `dev`. The main differences in each *Target* are:

     - Different `dest` (destination) paths for the resultant generated `.js`file(s).
     - For the `concat:dev` and `uglify:dev` *Targets* its `options` object defines the configuration for the resultant Source Map file.
   - At the end of `Gruntfile.js` three different `grunt.registerTask()` have been defined. Each one defines a [taskList](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks) that essentially defines which *Task* and *Target* to run in the order specified.

     For example consider the following registered task named `dist`:

     ```
     grunt.registerTask('dist', [
       'concat:dist',
       'uglify:dist',
       'processhtml:dist'
     ]);
     ```

     When running `grunt dist` via the command line Grunt essentially invokes this *Task*, which subsequently performs the following in this order:

     1. Firstly, runs the `dist` *Target* defined in the `concat` *Task*.
     2. Then runs the `dist` *Target* defined in the `uglify` *Task*.
     3. Finally, runs the `dist` *Target* defined in the `processhtml` *Task*.
4. **Running Gruntfile.js (above) and its output**

   1. Running the following command via the command line:

      ```
      grunt dev
      ```

      outputs the following additional assets to the project directory:

      ```
      project
      ├── ...
      ├── dev
      │   ├── index.html
      │   └── js
      │       ├── bundle.min.js
      │       └── bundle.min.js.map
      └── ...
      ```

      As you can see it has:

      - Created a new `dev` folder in the root of the project directory.
      - The two `<script>` elements originally defined in `project/src/index.html` have been substituted in the newly generated `project/dev/index.html` with a single `<script>` tag as follows:

        ```html
        <script src="js/bundle.min.js"></script>
        ```
      - Both files; `project/src/js/a.js` and `project/src/js/b.js`, have been concatenated and minified in the resultant `project/dev/js/bundle.min.js`.
      - The following source map file has been generated; `project/dev/js/bundle.min.js.map`. This file essentially maps back to the original `project/src/js/a.js` and `project/src/js/b.js` files.
   2. Running the following command via the command line:

      ```
      grunt dist
      ```

      outputs the following additional assets to the project directory:

      ```
      project
      ├── ...
      ├── dist
      │   ├── index.html
      │   └── js
      │       └── bundle.min.js
      └── ...
      ```

      As you can see this time it has;

      - Created a `dist` folder in the root of the project directory.
      - Again, the two `<script>` elements originally defined in `project/src/index.html` have been substituted in the newly generated `project/dist/index.html`  with a single `<script>` tag (as per the aforementioned `dev` *Task*).
      - Again, both files; `project/src/js/a.js` and `project/src/js/b.js`, have been concatenated and minified in the resultant `project/dist/js/bundle.min.js`.
      - However, the main notable difference is that *NO source map file has been created.*
   3. Running the following command via the command line:

      ```
      grunt
      ```

      will produce both the outputs defined in the previous steps 1 and 2.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you so much!